# WAS 7.0 Application error 500 (initialization failure)

Tags: java, jvm, websphere, centos7

I'm the administrator of WAS. Now it's necessary to move the web application (on the Websphere Application Server platform) from Windows to Linux. The WebSphere itself is installed normally, Application is installed and started normally, but an error occurs when viewing the application through the browser. 
Here is `Error 500: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory (initialization failure).`
The question is: this happens on different assemblies of the CentOS, on one it works, on the other one is not. On Windows all works fine. What could be the problem? Do not have the necessary packages in CentOS or do I need to install some kind of library? Sorry for my bad english. Thank you!

Comment: For the root exception causing the initialization failure, search your logs for "<clinit>" - that's the method name of the static initializer, and it should show up in the stack trace of the exception causing the init failure..

Comment: Regarding the behavior differences on multiple systems... check your WEB-INF/lib (or any similar utility directories, such as shared library directories or EAR/lib) for duplicates. For class paths that are assembled from the entire contents of a directory, the order of the jars on the class path is indeterminate, so you can't force duplicates to be picked up in a specific order (plus you can't use them both anyway, so there's not really any reason to do that).  The order can vary from system to system based on things like file system configuration.